# Reload parent window when parent window changes

Tags: javascript, java

I want to refresh the parent window after closing the pop up window.
I have used

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

This works fine in one case when the parent window is the calling window. But there is another scenario where we set the parent of the calling window as another window.

So instead of loading the calling parent window it loads the other page. Can we set a fixed parent window as in my case its obviously changing due to some business rules.

Comment: Look into SessionStorage

Comment: Could you post in the code that you have tried?